# load average calculation using top

Tags: linux, top, load

I'm working on performance testing of application and would like to validate the performance of the server during testing. Currently, the server is a 16 multiprocessor with single core on each CPU.

I'm validating the CPU utilization of the server using the top command and I'm getting the load average value as 0.47,0.37,0.22. I'm trying to understand the load average of the server however, getting confused. Does the value show for single CPU or for 16 CPUs available?

Kindly help with answers. Also please help with other commands to validate the performance of server.

Comment: What do you mean by "validate the performance"?

Comment: It's a total for the entire machine, no matter how many cores.  However, "load average" probably doesn't mean what you think it means.   It doesn't really tell you anything about performance.  It tells you how many processes were in a "runnable or uninterruptible state" in the past 1, 5, and 15 minutes.  i.e. roughly how "busy" the machine has been recently.  See, e.g, `man uptime` for a little more detail.   Also search for "load average" and related terms on google/duckduckgo/wherever.  See all the "Related" links on the right-hand side of this page too.